# Ambito de las variables en OpenMP

Tags: c++, c, multitasking

Según entiendo al declarar una variable de tipo privado en OpenMP, esta no se inicializa, simplemente realiza la reserva de memoria y al salir del ámbito parallel, esta recupera su valor inicial.

La duda surge cuando implícitamente dicha variable es shared. Esta sera compartida por todos sus hilos y al salir del ámbito parallel, continua teniendo el valor obtenido en la n-ésima iteracion del ámbito privado (debido a lastPrivate).

Por lo tanto, podemos afirmar que las variables shared a diferencia de las private mantienen el valor de sus variables una vez que termina el ambito de ejecución paralela y pasamos a ejecucion secuencial?

Os dejo un ejemplo en codigo de lo expusto anteriormente:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(){
    int iam, np, i, x;
    x=1234;
#pragma omp parallel private(iam, np,i)
{
  printf("Soy el thread %d, antes de actualizar, con x=%d \n",iam,x);
  #pragma omp for lastprivate(x) schedule(dynamic)
    for(i=0;i<11;i++)
    {
      x=iam*i;
      printf("\tSoy el thread %d, actualizando en for, i=%d x=%d\n",iam,i,x);
    }
  printf("\t\tSoy el thread %d, despues de actualizar, con x=%d \n",iam,x);
  }
printf("\n Despues de pragma parallel x=%d \n\n",x);
}
```